# AngularJs, how to set empty string in URL

Tags: angularjs

In the controller I have below function:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "administrator/listAuthor/{authorName}/{pageNo}", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/json")
    public List<Author> listAuthors(@PathVariable(value = "authorName") String authorName,
            @PathVariable(value = "pageNo") Integer pageNo) {
        try {
            if (authorName == null) {
                authorName = "";
            }
            if (pageNo == null) {
                pageNo = 1;
            }
            return adminService.listAuthor(authorName, pageNo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This function fetches and returns data from mysql database based on "authorName" and "pageNo". For example, when "authorName = a" and "pageNo = 1" I have:

[Data I get when "authorName = a" and "pageNo = 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwu0D.png)

Now I want to set "authorName" as ""(empty string), so that I can fetch all the data from mysql database (because the SQL statement "%+""+%" in backend will return all the data).

What can I do if I want to set authorName = empty string?

http://localhost:8080/spring/administrator/listAuthor/{empty string}/1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't use a path variable for such a usecase. Use a request parameter.

Comment: do you also want `authorName='); DROP DATABASE; --`?

Comment: @YOU What did you mean?...

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. RequestParam is an alternative.

Comment: @JBNizet But I still want to use PathVariable so that I can type urls in chrome anytime to check the data. :(

Comment: Why do you think you can't type a URL in Chrome with a request param? `http://localhost:8080/spring/administrator/listAuthor?authorName=foo&pageNo=1`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thats nice! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can encode empty sting to url, what I suggest you to do is to declare some constant that will be your code to empty string - such as null.

Example:

```
administrator/listAuthor/null/90
```

Afterwards , on server side, check if authorName is null and set local parameter with empty stirng accordingly.

Comment: But it will become confusing if there is an author named "null" :(. Maybe I can use other special strings like "!@#$%^" when authorName is null, but I still want to know if I can "literally" set authorName as empty.

Comment: The url that you write in ascii letters isn't sent as is, it is encoded by sender and decoded by the receiver  When encoding ascii letters the empty strings are escaped, so you cannot send latterly empty string.

Comment: You can send  %81 as empty stirng check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp , but you'll need to set it after the url being encoded.